# How to flatten a nested list to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

For example, say I have a nested list with the values

```
[['10', 'k', '19', 'p', '30'], ['11', 'f', '12', 'k', '15']]
```

And I want to create a nested dictionary with the format:

```
{
10: {'k': 19, 'p': 20},
11: {'f': 12,'k':  15}
}
```

The values are always in pairs (letter and number like k and 19)

How might I go about this? So far I've just used a simple function to create an empty dictionary and add all the keys but it seems to go on forever.

Comment: why "using lambda functions" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler Solution (from @Jon):

```
{int(k): {a: int(b) for a, b in zip(*[iter(v)]*2)} for k, *v in list1}
```

This keeps the integers all right.

---

Try:

```
{i[0]:{k:m for k,m in zip(i[1::2],i[2::2])} for i in list1 }
```

Here:

```
list1 = [[' 10', 'k', '19', 'p', '30'], [' 11', 'f', '12', 'k', '15']]
```

Gives:

```
{' 10': {'k': '19', 'p': '30'}, ' 11': {'f': '12', 'k': '15'}}
```

If you want them as int:

```
{int(i[0]):{k:int(m) for k,m in zip(i[1::2],i[2::2])} for i in list1 }
```

Gives:

```
{10: {'k': 19, 'p': 30}, 11: {'f': 12, 'k': 15}}
```

---

A solution for:

```
[['10', 'k', '19', 'p', '30'], ['11', 'f', '12', 'k', '15'], ['10', 'k', '20', 'm', '23']]
```

Is:

```
dic = {}
for i in list1:
    if int(i[0]) not in dic:
        dic[int(i[0])] = {k:int(m) for k,m in zip(i[1::2],i[2::2])}
    else:
        dic[int(i[0])].update({k:int(m) for k,m in zip(i[1::2],i[2::2])})
```

Comment: It needs to be in a nested dictionary. Do you know how I can create the nested list to be a dictionary instead? Also thanks

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese think the only option you're missing is probably with zip and extended unpacking, eg: `{k: {a: int(b) for a, b in zip(*[iter(v)]*2)} for k, *v in list1}`

Comment: Might as well make the first bit `int(k)` as well as seems the OP wants that one to be an integer...

Comment: What if there is a list:   [['10', 'k', '19', 'p', '30'], ['11', 'f', '12', 'k', '15'], ['10', 'k', '20', 'm', '23']]?  How come it doesn't give {10: {'k': '39', 'p': '30', 'm', '23'}, 11: {'f': 12, 'k': 15}}

Comment: thats not a list

Comment: you want it like that? but where did 20 come from?

Comment: sorry i accidentally posted that

Comment: @chr09 where did 20 come from?

Comment: the 20 belongs to the K

Comment: @chr09 i've added that

Comment: @chr09 check the answer's lowest part

Answer (score 3):

You can use this comprehension:

```
{k[0]:k[1] 
 for k in [(l[0], {l[m]:int(l[m+1]) for m in range(1, len(l), 2)}) 
           for l in list1] }
```

Which ouputs

```
{' 10': {'k': 19, 'p': 30}, ' 11': {'f': 12, 'k': 15}}
```